# Http OPTION REQUEST with cors in web api with authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I am using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors to support cross origin request as per this

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

My web apis are configured to use windows authentication and every request coming from angular has withCredentials set to true. Everything is working with HTTP GET but with PUT request sends preflight request which in getting unauthorised. My question is does Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors support configuration of OPTION request.

Comment: In my experience, parameters names maybe conflicting, try to use different names, and additionally you can post here your controller so that everyone can see and help.

Comment: sorry whats parameters got to do with HTTP OPTIONS request. in fact as i understand there are no parameters passed in OPTION request

Comment: I mean, in your PUT request.

Comment: I tried send the same PUT request by opening chrome with disabled security and it worked fine. So seems like params are ok.

Comment: well, it will be hard for us to identify the issue without sample codes, config or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Global.asax.cs

(I'm sure you either found a solution or gave up, but this is the link that I found on Google while looking for a solution to this.)

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers.GetValues("Origin")[0]);
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        Response.End();
    }
}
```